# scrapy spider not following link to another page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm referencing from this [tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) and it works for getting data on the first page, and the following a link afterwards.

However, in my example, I am trying to check if listing has `3` things before I click on the listing link:

1. item must have business name
2. item must have phone number
3. item must have a website

If so, I want `scrapy` to click on the business link that goes to the business profile where I am able to retrieve the email.

After that, I want `scrapy` to go back to the main page and repeat the process for the rest of 19 listings on that page.

Yet, it outputs a list of duplicates like this:

[image]

```
service_name = input("Input Industry: ")
city = input("Input The City: ")


class Item(scrapy.Item):    
    business_name = scrapy.Field()
    phonenumber = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
    website = scrapy.Field()

class Bbb_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bbb"

    start_urls = [
        "http://www.yellowbook.com/s/"+ service_name + "/" + city
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.seen_business_names = []
        self.seen_websites = []
        self.seen_emails = []


    def parse(self, response):
        for business in response.css('div.listing-info'):
            item = Item()
            item['business_name'] = business.css('div.info.l h2 a::text').extract()
            item['website'] = business.css('a.s_website::attr(href)').extract()
            for x in item['business_name'] and item['website']:
                if x not in self.seen_business_names and item['website']:
                    if item['business_name']:
                        if item['website']:
                            item['phonenumber'] = business.css('div.phone-number::text').extract_first()
                            for href in response.css('div.info.l h2 a::attr(href)'):
                                yield response.follow(href, self.businessprofile)

            for href in response.css('ul.page-nav.r li a::attr(href)'):
                yield response.follow(href, self.parse)

    def businessprofile(self, response):
        for profile in response.css('div.profile-info.l'):
            item = Item()
            item['email'] = profile.css('a.email::text').extract()
            for x in item['email']:
                if x not in self.seen_emails:
                    self.seen_business_names.append(x)
                    yield item
python scrapy
```

Any suggestions on how to improve the code?

Comment: Maybe you haven't uploaded one image.

Comment: sorry about that now i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the guide thorougly before doing a spider. To populate items, you should use an [Item Loader](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html), that can have [post and pre-processors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors) useful for your purpose.
For duplication, [you can use a custom pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors).